# Can be Selection or ActiveRange an optional parameter?

Tags: vba, excel, selection

i've been trying to write down some code snippets in VBA for excel.
I tried to make this:

```
Sub populate(Optional ByVal r As Range = Selection)
'
' This only populates a selected range with each row number 
' 
   Dim a As Range
    For Each a In r
        a = a.Row
    Next

End Sub
```

But when i run it says that I have to make the optional parameter has to be constant. Same when i call it `populate(Selection)` or `populate(ActiveRange)`

Is possible to make what i'm trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've noticed, you cannot default an optional parameter to a non-constant. However, if you change the parameter's variable type to *Variant* you can use the `IsMissing` function to determine if a values was passed to the sub and reassign it if not.

```
Sub Populate(Optional r As Variant)
    If IsMissing(r) Then Set r = Selection
    Dim a As Range
    For Each a In r
        a = a.Row
    Next
    Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

If you simply call or run `Call Populate`, it determines that *r* has not been passed to it and uses *Selection*. If *r* (in this case a range of one or more cells) is passed into the sub like `Call Populate(Range("A1:D5"))`, it uses that instead.

See [IsMissing function](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/IsMissing-Function-22286f0f-d1e7-4ce4-96d0-7691a3944bf1) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast objects or assign variables  in the procedure arguments.

Here's a better wait to do it.

Define your sub

```
Sub populateSub(r As Range)
    For Each a In r
        a = a.Row
    Next 
End Sub
```

and call it from another sub. By convention, people use a sub called `Main`.

```
 Sub Main()
   PopulateSub Selection
End Sub
```